# How do i set backgroundImage on a single component?

Tags: reactjs, css, background-image

I am trying to set `backgroundImage` on a single component in a React project. If I attach it to the `body` element it will display as the `backgroundImage` on ALL components. if i set it to the **.wrapperContainer** element of the current component it will display like this

[image: How it looks on .wrapperContainer]

But the desired output I want is this (without the background image being displayed on all other components)

[image: Desired look]

CSS:

```
body {
  background: url("../../services/images/hehe.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover; 

  animation: increase 60s linear 10ms infinite;
  -webkit-transition: all 5.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 5.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 5.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 5.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 5.2s ease-in-out;
  z-index: -2;

  background-color: #f6f8fa;
}
```

React:

```
return (
  <div className="wrapperContainer"> /*This is the element i replace .body with*/
    <Card className="wrapperCard">
      xxxxxxx
      xxxxx
      xxx
    </Card>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this if it helps

```
return (
  <div className="wrapperContainer" style={ { background: 'url("../../services/images/hehe.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed' } }> /*This is the element i replace .body with*/
    <Card className="wrapperCard">
       xxxxxxx
       xxxxx
       xxx
    </Card>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to STACK Arasto. You can set it to the component name you want. For example you have background to appear only in `Card` component.

Now assume the render function of Card looks like this:

```
<div className="bg-apply">

</div>
```

You can add a class to the parent div in Card component and add style to that class as you did in your question. That way the style/background image will only be applied to this particular div/component.

```
bg-apply {
background: url("../../services/images/hehe.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover; 
animation: increase 60s linear 10ms infinite;
-webkit-transition: all 5.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 5.2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 5.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 5.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 5.2s ease-in-out;
z-index: -2;
background-color: #f6f8fa;
}
```

Comment: Hi Vishal,
Much gratitude for taking your time to reply to my issue.
I've made a div wrapper on the parent component 'LoginPage.js' and added the same css to it, but it stil gets applied to all other componenets aswell. 
I cant seem to isolate it to the single component. 


  

`render() {
        return (
        <div className="wrapper"> /*the parent wrapper */
            <LoginForm submit={this.submit} />
        </div>
        )
    }
`


i made a new css file with the same code as the one abow to this wrapper and unfortunatley it stil gets applied to all components.

Comment: @ArastoSahbaei In css you need to use selector like div.wrapper so it only applies to 1 particular div.